# Running unit test on JS runtime for es6 import statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, es6-modules

I am very new to NodeJS and JS as well. I have tried reading about resources like babel and rewire which help in resolving dependencies of ES6. But ended up being confused.

I am trying to write unit test for a JS runtime file which has import statements. The issue is that this file is a runtime file. This means that the import module only works when running in browser inside the dependent platform/application.

runtimeFile.js

```
import {something} from 'other-module'

function foo(){
}

export const toBeTested = {
    foo
}
```

unitTest.js

```
const toBeTested = require('./runtimeFile').toBeTested

describe('some test', () => {
    it('test a func', () => {
          const result = tobeTested.foo();
      });
});
```

When i try to run this unit test using mocha getting:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

This is for the import statement in runtimeFile.js.

So my question is around:

1. How do i mock the import statement
2. I am not sure what configuartion i need to do in order to get rid of this syntax error

I can provide more information as needed

Comment: you are missing brackets on the `function foo {}` line. it should be something like `function foo() {}`. as for you 'how to mock the import statement' part I can't really help... I am not familiar with mocha.

Comment: there is a valuable discussion which took place on the jest GitHub repo tho... maybe you can make something out of it. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936

Comment: Why is your test file using require and your subject file using import? You must have a babel config, what dies it look like?

Comment: I dont have a babel-config.